# Maytag Dishwasher

Tags: dishwasher

The air vent is located on top of the door (upper left corner). Hot steam comes out and has discolored the granite. I called Maytag and was told it could be the seal around the door. The service tech came today and said it is not the door seal because the dishwasher is not leaking on the floor. He said it was a poor design. Any suggestions on how to stop the steam from coming out and discoloring the granite?

Comment: get a dishwasher that has the vent in a different place

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I think @jsotola has as good an answe as you'll get without more info. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.